# How to create a gradient progress bar with a fixed gradient

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, gradient

I'm rather new to HTML and CSS. I'd like to create a progress bar that has a gradient background which it masked to the whole element but only visible on the bar itself. So far I've only managed to get the result shown below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ICAJ.png). Ive tried to achieve the result shown in the second image by manipulating other background properties such as background-attachment, but then the gradient itself does not fit anymore. I've also tried to give the parent of the bar a gradient background and simply draw a white div above the remaining space but that solution prohibited me from adding a border radius to the bar itself. Any help is highly appreciated. Cheers!

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ICAJ.png)

[What I've got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PadxR.png)

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  background: black;
}

.progress-bar-indicator {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green, blue);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#indicator-1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#indicator-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

#indicator-3 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" id="indicator-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" id="indicator-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" id="indicator-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using mask that will work with dynamic width:

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  background: black;
  position:relative; /* relative here */
}

.progress-bar-indicator {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
   /* this will do the magic */
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
}
.progress-bar-indicator::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green, blue); /* your gradient here */
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" style="width:80%"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" style="width:50%"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" style="width:30%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep the gradient width the same as the container width.

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  background: black;
}

.progress-bar-indicator {
  height: 100%; 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green, blue);
  /*                ↓ same as container width */  
  background-size: 500px 100%;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#indicator-1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#indicator-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

#indicator-3 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" id="indicator-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" id="indicator-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar-indicator" id="indicator-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  animation-direction: reverse;
  background: #e5405e;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #e5405e 0%, #ffdb3a 25%, #3fffa2 50%, #3fffa2 50%, #1a9be0 73%, #ba68ed 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e5405e 0%, #ffdb3a 25%, #3fffa2 50%, #3fffa2 50%, #1a9be0 73%, #ba68ed 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e5405e 0%, #ffdb3a 25%, #3fffa2 50%, #3fffa2 50%, #1a9be0 73%, #ba68ed 100%);
}

.shrinker {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.timelapse {
  animation-name: timelapse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86, .05, .4, .96);
}

@keyframes timelapse {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div class="child progress"></div>
        <div class="child shrinker timelapse"></div>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xq2ervwf/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I've also stumbled across that solution previously. My problem was adding a border radius to the bar itself.